# word for squeezing your body while in cold

Tags: word-choice, phrase-usage

Sometimes I squeeze my body like crossing my arms and hunching my shoulders in cold weather.

Is there any word which I can use to describe this activity?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you can say you are *bracing* yourself.

Comment: @DamkerngT. - I think you mean "**embracing** yourself". One might also say _hugging myself_, but I think this would most often be described as _wrapping my arms around myself_.

Comment: @J.R. Yes. These two words confuse me very often. Thank you.

Comment: @Damk - Although it's worth mentioning that one can _brace himself against the elements_ (meaning bad weather), but that's usually said in a figurative sense.

Answer (score 2):

The word I thought of is *huddled*, as in, "I was huddled in the cold."

The word doesn't necessarily mean that you've wrapped your arms around yourself (I usually imagine someone hunched over a little bit, with their shoulders up), but self-embracing woudln't be necessarily be excluded, either. NOAD defines the word as:

> **huddle** (*verb*)
>   crowd together; nestle closely : *they huddled together for warmth*.
>   • curl one's body into a small space : *the watchman remained, huddled under his canvas shelter*.

Another interesting aspect of the word *huddled* is how it can use different prepositions:

[image: huddled]

It think *huddled in the cold* and *huddled against the cold* pretty much mean the same thing. I don't usually wrap my arms around myself when I'm huddling in the wind, but someone else might.

For what it's worth, when I searched for images of *huddled in the cold*, I found this one:

[image]

They don't have their arms around themselves, but they are using their arms while attempting to stay warm.